# Synology Upload API is not responding. just timeout

Tags: node.js, axios, nestjs, synology

My Code is Here.

I want to upload files to synology using nestjs.
but it's not running my expected.

synology is not responding until timeout.

Where is the problem in my code?

https://global.download.synology.com/download/Document/Software/DeveloperGuide/Package/FileStation/All/enu/Synology_File_Station_API_Guide.pdf
(FormData is not 'form-data')

```
  // Service
  import { HttpService } from '@nestjs/axios';

  constructor(private readonly http: HttpService) {}

  async uploadFile(files: File[], file_path: string) {
    try {
      const formData = new FormData();
      for (const file of files) {
        formData.append('file', file);
      }

      const data = await firstValueFrom(
        this.http
          .post(process.env.SYNOLOGY_URL, formData, {
            params: {
              api: 'SYNO.FileStation.Upload',
              version: 2,
              method: 'upload',
              _sid: this.sid,
              path: file_path,
              create_parents: false,
              overwrite: false,
            },
          })
          .pipe(map((response) => response.data)),
      );
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(JSON.stringify(error, null, 2));
    }
  }
```

timeout response

```
{
  "message": "timeout of 10000ms exceeded",
  "name": "AxiosError",
  "stack": "AxiosError: timeout of 10000ms exceeded\n    at RedirectableRequest.handleRequestTimeout (/usr/projects/backend/init_nestjs/node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:647:16)\n    at RedirectableRequest.emit (node:events:518:28)\n    at Timeout.<anonymous> (/usr/projects/backend/init_nestjs/node_modules/follow-redirects/index.js:210:12)\n    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:573:17)\n    at processTimers (node:internal/timers:514:7)\n    at Axios.request (/usr/projects/backend/init_nestjs/node_modules/axios/lib/core/Axios.js:45:41)",
  "config": {
    "transitional": {
      "silentJSONParsing": true,
      "forcedJSONParsing": true,
      "clarifyTimeoutError": false
    },
    "adapter": [
      "xhr",
      "http"
    ],
    "transformRequest": [
      null
    ],
    "transformResponse": [
      null
    ],
    "timeout": 10000,
    "xsrfCookieName": "XSRF-TOKEN",
    "xsrfHeaderName": "X-XSRF-TOKEN",
    "maxContentLength": -1,
    "maxBodyLength": -1,
    "env": {},
    "headers": {
      "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
      "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data; boundary=axios-1.6.8-boundary-KyPk5XLtcOCa_vHTRUxIf-PRY",
      "User-Agent": "axios/1.6.8",
      "Content-Length": "263074",
      "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, compress, deflate, br"
    },
    "maxRedirects": 5,
    "params": {
      "api": "SYNO.FileStation.Upload",
      "version": 2,
      "method": "upload",
      "_sid": "SYNOLOGY_SID"
      "path": "/docker",
      "create_parents": false,
      "overwrite": false
    },
    "method": "post",
    "url": "SYNOLOGY_URL/webapi/entry.cgi",
    "data": {}
  },
  "code": "ECONNABORTED",
  "status": null
}
```

using import * as FormData from 'form-data' instead of basic FormData.
because using formData.getHeaders().

but i show error 'source.on is not a function' when formData.append('file', file)

Answer (score 0):

--> `post(process.env.SYNOLOGY_URL, ...)`

I would definitely check first if `SYNOLOGY_URL` is in the environment

--> `env: {}`

Protip: if you're using `.env` file, its contents must be first loaded into the environment. For example, by `ConfigService` (which you're not using here), `dotenv` or anything like that. That's why skipping NestJS native configuration logic backfires in 99% cases.

Or, after another look:

```
"url": "SYNOLOGY_URL/webapi/entry.cgi",
```

Is that a correct URL?

On a third look, did you set the correct request header?

On a fourth look, grab `nestjs-http-promise` - you won't need to struggle with rxjs.

Comment: Thank you, answer. I test env replacing URL directly.
Another API is successfully running. get file info, file list API..
url value is modify to hide my synology url.

Answer (score 0):

I got it.

The solution is to put params data into formdata.

```
const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('api', 'SYNO.FileStation.Upload');
  formData.append('version', '2');
  formData.append('method', 'upload');
  formData.append('path', file_path);
  formData.append('create_parent', 'false');
  formData.append('overwrite', 'false');
  files.forEach(async (file: Express.Multer.File) => {
    const bufData = Buffer.from(file.buffer);
    const blobData = new Blob([bufData], {
      type: file.mimetype,
    });
    formData.append('file', blobData, file.originalname);
  });

  const data = await firstValueFrom(
    this.http
      .post(process.env.SYNOLOGY_URL, formData, {
        params: {
          _sid: this.sid,
        },
      })
      .pipe(map((response) => response.data)),
  );
```